# How to change individual entries in xarray.DataArray with sel?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have data inside an xarray.DataArray that I want to manipulate, however, it do not manage to change individual entries in the DataArray.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
data = np.random.rand(2,2)
times = [1998,1999]
locations = ['It','Be']

A = xr.DataArray(data, coords = [times, locations], dims = [time, space])
```

this gives me a DataArray. Now I want to set the entry for (1998,'It') manually to 5, but the following does not work:

```
A.sel(time = 1998, space = 'It').values = 5
```

neither this works:

```
A.sel(time = 1998, space = 'It').values = array(5)
```

the data remains as it is. However, strangely the following works out well:

```
A.sel(time = 1998).values[0] = 5
```

could you please explain me the logic behind this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xarray's assignment does not allow you to assign values to arrays using `sel` or `isel`. This is described in the documentation [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing). For your application, you probably want to use the `.loc` property:

```
A.loc[dict(time=1998, space='It')] = 5
```

It is also possible to use `DataArray.where` to replace values.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. works nicely with loc. Still, one can also change entries by the use of sel as described above and I do not understand why this wouldn't work for individual entries via the first approach from above.

Comment: Glad it works (feel free to accept the answer). Basically, assigning values to slices of numpy arrays is tricky (not just in xarray). You'll see a big warning section about this in the xarray docs (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing)

Comment: I just realized, that when you write `['It']` as a one element list, then the approach which I claimed to work, doesn't work either. So I'll stick to the loc command and won't mess around with the sel .

Comment: Is there a way to get method='nearest' functionality with this approach?